# Can I join Stack Overflow's testing team?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, testing

How can I participate in the Stack Overflow testing team?

Comment: from the comments, you suggest lots of bugs... do you actually mean *bugs*? If so, check whether they are reported here (and if not, report them). *Features* (i.e. things you'd choose to improve) are different; feel free to propose them, but note that you priorities and the team's may be different.

Comment: How to report them ?

Comment: Here. Create a question called "Bug: Something bad is happening" and include the details within the description.

Comment: Sure I will prepare with description and post questions

Comment: @Sampson: Please don't tell people to use tags in their title. Use the tags.

Comment: As Rich B said, don't put "Bug: " in the title, rather, use the `bug` tag! That way, they all show up on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think you are seeing lots of bugs then post them here. Someone will look into it and post a response, usually fairly quickly.

However, if you think you've found a critical exploitable security issue, you should email team@stackoverflow.com with the details instead of posting it publicly.

Make sure you include all the details - operating system, browser etc and include screen shots if possible.

Comment: Generally good advice.  If you identify what you believe to be a critical exploitable security issue, you should probably email team@stackoverflow.com instead of posting it publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Invitation, likely.

Invitations would logically be based on experience testing/developing software/websites, activity within the community itself, familiarity with SO and how it operates.

Plus, with SO having three (soon to be four) personalities, so much testing has already taken place. The *need* for more testing shrinks with each passing day. The system is stabilizing, and the community has become the prominent testing-force.

Comment: how to get those ?

Comment: consider myself i am feeling there lot bugs i am seeing in SO site , i would to participate for testing team to point those

Comment: Visit often. Answer questions. Offer suggestions, etc.

Comment: The Community. It's starting to sound like Stepford...or Hot Fuzz. For the greater good...

Answer (score 0):

What specific testing? The product is now long out of private beta... there are the site-specific betas, which mainly require you to [turn up](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/)...

We've also seen at least one feature arrive here on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) ahead of the other sites; so maybe "look carefully here"; but there usually is no trumpet... you might also watch [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

Other than that, most testing is internal to the team AFAIK.

Comment: functional testing